# How to determine carrier for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I have an iPhone 5c and I need to determine the carrier for it. How can I do this?

The phone is not currently activated and I do not have a sim. I need to determine the carrier so I know what sim to obtain.

Comment: Settings > carrier - or take the SIM out & look at it

Comment: The phone is not activated and I do not have a sim.

Comment: If the phone was ever activated you can go to 'Settings -> About' and look at the entry under 'Carrier'.  That should show the last carrier that it was locked to.  Do you see anything there?

Comment: I cannot get to settings at all. The phone is not currently activated.

Comment: lol you can't.. Unless it's on the box. Just try different sims. I never had problems switching sims in different countries? Are you assuming that your iPhone is carrier locked, or do you know it?